# Restrict what a user can see in an SQL query

Tags: sql

this is a bit out there, but I was wondering if it is possible to restrict a usergroup in SQL to only see certain subsets of data..

Say for example a table of products, ProductName and State are the two columns.  I only want a usergroup to see products from their state, when they do a query like `SELECT * FROM Products`

Is that possible?

Comment: Which DBMS? PostgreSQL? Oracle? DB2?

Answer (score 2):

Restrict access to the underlying table.

And give your user groups access to views on these underlying tables.

So:

Given table:

```
CREATE TABLE EVERYTHING ID INTEGER, TYPE CHAR(1), SEMISECRET CHAR(20), REALLYSECRECT CHAR(20));
```

You can create views which give access to only certain columns:-

```
CREATE VIEW SOMESTUFF AS SELECT ID, TYPE, SEMISECRET FROM EVERTHINK;
```

You can create views which give access to certain rows:-

```
CREATE VIEW TYPESLICE AS SELECT ID, TYPE, REALLYSECRECT WHERE TYPE ='X';
```

Much more is possible, but that's the basics.

Answer (score 1):

Create one or more views corresponding to your subsets and set the appropriate permissions on them.